# Conditional Distribution of Poisson Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X_{1}, \dots, X_{n}$ be independent Poisson random variables (parameter $\lambda$), and set $Y=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}$. Find the conditional probability mass function of the random variable $X_{i}$ given $Y=m$ for an integer $m$.

---

I have done the first part of the problem, where the distribution of the random variable $Y$ will be given by a Poisson random variable of parameter $n\lambda$ by using the mgf technique to identify the distribution of $Y$. However, I don't know how to compute $P(X_{i}=x | Y=m)$ since I don't know how to compute the joint pmf of $(X_{i},Y)$ (else, this should be straightforward).

How would one proceed with the problem? I initially though that $X$ and $Y$ could be independent, but I don't think that's the case.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/151272/321264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outline: We want to compute $\Pr(X_i=k\mid  Y=m)$. By the definition of conditional probability, this is
$$\frac{\Pr((X_i=k)\cap (Y=m))}{\Pr(Y=m)}.\tag{1}$$
Note that $0\le k\le m$.  You know how to compute the denominator, so we concentrate on the numerator.

The numerator is
$$\Pr(X_i=k)\Pr(W=m-k),$$
where $W$ is the sum of all the $X_j$ except for $X_i$.

You know how to compute $\Pr(W=m-k)$.

Now when you substitute in (1) there will be a pleasant amount of cancellation.

Comment: Sounds great. However, why would the probability of the intersection of the events be:

$P(X_{i}=k)P(W=m-k)$

for $W$ being the sum of all the $X_{j}$ except for $X_{i}$? Do you use independence? I'm not sure on how to arrive at that step. The rest seems doable. Thanks!

Comment: We have $X_i=k$ **and** $Y=m$ if $X_i=k$ and the rest of the $X_j$ make up the rest of $m$, meaning they add up to $m-k$. Now use the fact that $X_i$ and the sum of the rest of the $X_j$ are independent random variables, so we multiply.

Comment: The expressions will at first look a bit messy. But after the smoke clears, you should find that the conditional distribution of $X_i$ given $Y=m$ is binomial.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot. There is one last point though, how do you know that $X_{i}$ and the sum of the rest of the $X_{j}$ are independent random variables? Intuitively it seems obvious, but is there a way to rigorously prove this?

Comment: You are welcome. By the way the parameters of the $X_k$ need not be all the same, again we get a binomial distribution. And the joint distribution of the $X_i$, given $Y=m$, is multinomial.

Comment: Yes, there is a way to  prove it, if the $X_i$ are independent, then any function of some of the variables is independent of any function of the rest of the variables. Formal proof is too long for a comment.  Pretty easy for the discrete case.