# Computing a conditional Poisson distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, expected-value, poisson-distribution

Suppose that $X_1, \dots, X_n$ are i.i.d. $Poisson(\theta)$. I want to compute the expected value of the number of zeros in $X_1, \dots, X_n$ conditioned on the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = m$. In other words,

$E [\#(X_i = 0)|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = m]$

To do so, I first tried to compute the conditional distribution. Let $C = \#(X_i = 0)$, we have

$p(C = c|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = m) = \frac{p(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = m|C = c)p(C=c)}{p(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = m)}$.

I derived

$p(C = c) = Binomial(n, e^{-\theta})$

$p(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = m) = Poisson(n\theta)$

$p(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = m|C = c) = p(\sum_{l=1}^{n-k} X_{i_l} = m) = Poisson((n-c)\theta)$

When I compute the conditional distribution, I get 
$p(C = c|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = m) = \frac{(n-c)^m {n \choose c} (1-e^{-\theta})^{n-c}}{n^m}$. I'm not sure whether I have computed this distribution correctly (not sure if it even sums to one) and I don't know how to proceed from here to compute the expected value.

Comment: The joint  distribution of the $X_i$ conditional on $\sum_n X_i = m$ is mutinomial, with $n$ categories, total size $m$, and all category probs equal to $1/n$. So your conditional expectation is $n$ times the probability that a $B(m,1/n)$ random variable is zero, that is, $n (1-1/n)^m$.

Comment: @kimchilover Could you explain why all category probabilities are equal to $1/n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The joint distribution of $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ conditional on $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=m$ is the multinomial distribution $M(p,m)$ where the $n$-long vector of category probabilities is $p=(1/n,1/n,\ldots,1/n)$.

This is a standard textbook fact, curiously absent from the Wikipedia article on the multinomial distribution, but given in one of the [sources](https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat504/node/48/) it cites.  Also in an old [SEM question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151272/proof-that-conditional-of-poisson-distribution-is-binomial), for the Poison/Binomial case.  In general, if $X_i\sim Po(\lambda_i)$, then conditional on $\sum_1^n X_i = m$, the joint distribution of 
 $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is $k$-category multinomial $M(p,m)$ where the $i$-th entry of $p$ is $\lambda_i/\sum\lambda_j$.  The proof is not tricky: the ratio of the $\exp(-\lambda)$ terms simplifies away, and the ratio of the $k!$ terms becomes the multinomial coefficient.

In your case, the conditional distribution of the individual $X_i$ is binomial with params $m$ and $1/n$, so the chance that $X_i=0$ is $(1-1/n)^m$.