# Magical relationship between Exponential distribution and Poisson process

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, equivalence-relations, gamma-distribution

Consider i.i.d. random variables $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ satisfying exponential distribution $\operatorname{Exp}(1)$. Let $Y=X_1+X_2+\ldots+X_n$. We know that the p.d.f. of $Y$ is the Gamma distribution
$$
f_Y(t)=\frac{t^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}e^{-t}, (t\geq 0).
$$
What surprised me is that this is exactly the p.m.f. of a Poisson distribution with parameter $t$. Define a Poisson process with rate $1$, $N_t$, then $\frac{t^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}e^{-t}$ equals $P(N_t=n-1)$. Since we can define Poisson process with i.i.d. exponentials, we actually can write
$$
P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}X_i\leq t, \sum_{i=1}^n X_i>t\right)= P(N_t=n-1)=\frac{t^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}e^{-t}.
$$

I believe there must exist a intuitive explanation of this relationship. But I couldn’t find it.

Comment: Inter arrival times in a Poisson process are i.i.d. exponential.

Comment: and the Gamma distribution is for the time of the nth arrival.

Comment: Not less, not more magical than the following [connection](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/151272/305862).

Answer (score 1):

I will give an intuitive explanation, only needing the defining properties of the Poisson Process and the exponential distribution, without needing any calculations involving densities.  
In short, the Poisson Process having *independent and stationary increments* and the exponential distribution being [*memoryless*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorylessness) explains this connection:

More precisely, the Poisson Process is an $\mathbb N_0$-valued process with the property that for all $s,t>0$ we have that $N_{t+s}-N_t$ and $N_t$ are independent, or more generally that for $t_0<t_1<\dots<t_k$ that $$N_{t_k}-N_{t_{k-1}},\dots, N_{t_1}-N_{t_0}$$ are independent. In simpler terms, the knowledge that $x$ jumps occured in the time interval $[t_{i-1},t_i)$ does not help you predict the amount of jumps that occured in the time interval $[t_i,t_{i+1})$.  Furthermore, the distribution of  $N_{t+s}-N_t$, i.e. the jumps in the time interval $[t,t+s)$, is the same as the one of $N_s$, i.e. the jumps in the time interval $[0,s)$. Hence the distribution of the amount of jumps only depends on the length of the time interval.

The exponential distribution being memoryless means that if $T\sim\text{Exp}(\lambda)$ for all $x,y>0$ we have $$\mathbb P\bigg[T>x+y\big| T>y\bigg]=\mathbb P[T>x].$$ In simpler terms, if you know that $T>y$, than the probability that $T$ is greater than an additional amount of $x$ is exactly the same as the probability that $T$ was greater than $x$ in the first place.

Now we are ready to see the connection: For simplicity, let $T$ be the distribution of the first jump of the Poisson Process $N$. Then by definition $$\begin{align*}\mathbb P\bigg[T>t+s\big|T>t\bigg]&=\mathbb P\bigg[N_{t+s}=0\big| N_t=0\bigg] \\ &=\mathbb P\bigg[N_{t+s}-N_t=0\big| N_t=0\bigg] \\ (\text{independence of increments}) &= \mathbb P[N_{t+s}-N_t=0] \\ (\text{stationarity of increments})&= \mathbb P[N_s=0] = \mathbb P[T>s] \end{align*}$$
Thus we have shown that $T$ must be memoryless. Once we convince ourselves that the distribution of $T$ must also be continuous, we necessarily have that $T$ follows an exponential distribution, as they are the only memoryless distributions without atoms.

You may try to repeat this argument for not only the first waiting time $T$, as I have done above, but for more general interarrival times, i.e. the times between consecutive jumps. Then you will have shown that the waiting times of a homogeneous Poisson Process are i.i.d. exponentially distributed, as @geetha290krm already noted.